# Where am I adding the space in this C printf snippet?

Tags: c, printf

```
void display(const char *label, double used,
             int const warning, int const critical, int const decimals)
{
  if (critical != 0 && used > critical) {
    printf("<span color='%s'>%s</span><span color='%s'>", COLOR_RED, label, COLOR_RED);
  } else if (warning != 0 && used > warning) {
    printf("<span color='%s'>%s</span><span color='%s'>", COLOR_ORANGE, label, COLOR_ORANGE);
  } else {
    printf("<span color='%s'>%s</span><span color='%s'>", COLOR_GREEN, label, COLOR_GREEN);
  }

  printf("%*.*lf</span>\n", decimals + 3 + 1, decimals, used);
}
```

visiting this code (and C) after a long time, The above snippet results in...

`<span color='#00FF00'></span><span color='#00FF00'> 2.26</span>`

...which is as intended, other than the `<SPACE>` in front of 2.26. Where am I adding it? How do I get rid of it??!!

Comment: This should be thanks to length specifation for `%*.*lf`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the caller of this function.

Comment: It looks as though there will be *two* spaces. If `decimals` is `2` then the field width is `6` and `2.26` is only `4` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OK as it is linked to your formatting. You are using `%*.*lf` but with your current results, your `decimals` variable holds value of `2` (since result has 2 digits after decimal point).

So then, your formatting is equivalent to `%6.2lf` with input data of `2.26` which resutls to `2` spaces, with final result of   `2.26`.

If you want to fully remove front spaces, use `%.*lf` and pass only `decimals` for parameter, that being then `printf("%.*lf", decimals, number)`.